# How many Girls that play an Instrument are in the Sample?

Tags: probability

- 300 students are asked, if they play a musical instrument.
- Half of the students asked were boys and half girls.
- 2/3 of students said they played a musical instrument. The rest did not play a musical insturment.
- 80 boys play an instrument.

The School want to interview a sample of 60 students on musical interests. How many girls that play a instrument will be in the sample?

Comment: Problem is ill-defined. From data we know $200$ play, of whom $120$ must be girls. But this tells us nothing useful about the composition of the sample of $60$. If it is randomly chosen, one can say something about the *expected* (mean) number of girls who play an instrument, namely $(60)(1/2)(120/150)$, but the actual number is not determined.

Comment: Please use more descriptive titles. Imagine how the main page would look if all questions had titles like that.

Comment: Andre Nicolas, try it now

Comment: @Leah: The wording is clearer. Assume that the sample of $60$ is random. Here is a simple example that illustrates the issue. Question: A fair coin is tossed $10$ times. How many heads will there be? The *mean* number of heads is $5$. But the actual number might not be $5$.  In fact, the probability of exactly $5$ is a bit under $25$%. In your problem, the mean number is $24$. But it is quite unlikely that the number will be exactly $24$.  If the school chooses not randomly, but on the basis of sex (half and half) and then to represent musical interests, then yes, the answer is exactly $24$.

Answer (score 3):

$\frac{2}{3}300=\color{red}{200}$ play an instrument. There are $\color{blue}{150}$ boys. 
Let's set it up like:
$$
\begin{matrix}
&\text{boys}&\text{girls}&\text{total}\\
\text{ play}&80&120&\color{red}{200}\\
\text{don't}&70&30\\
\text{total}& \color{blue}{150}
\end{matrix}
$$

So on average you'll have $\frac{120}{300}\cdot 60= 24$ girls in your sample that play an instrument.